# How to transpose html elements in Dart when user clicks

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have one or more collections of html elements as follows:

```dart
<div class="input-group symbol-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon symbol"></span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" />
</div>
```

Further up the page I have a `TextInputElement` that changes the text of any `span.symbol` to whatever is entered in it (ie. £, $ etc.). So far, so good.

What I want to do is, based on a user selection, swap any of these spans with the corresponding `TextInputElement` so that the `span.symbol` appears ***after*** the TextInputElement (or ***before*** if after is already selected).

How do I do this?

EDIT:
Sorry I forgot to add my current code (which works but assumes only 2 children in the Element):

```dart
<Element>
..onClick.listen((Event e) {
    querySelectorAll('div.symbol-group').forEach((DivElement e) {
        Element e1 = e.children.first;
        Element e2 = e.children.elementAt(1);

        e.children.clear();
        e.append(e2);
        e.append(e1);


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have still troubles to understand what you try to accomplish.
Just have a look at my attempt and comment how it doesn't yet do what you need.

```dart
..onClick.listen((Event e) {
    querySelectorAll('div.symbol-group').forEach((DivElement e) {
        Element e1 = e.querySelector('span.input-group-addon.symbol');
        Element e2 = e.querySelector('input.form-control');
        int i1 = e.indexOf(e1);
        int i2 = e.indexOf(e2);

        if(i1 < i2) {
          e1.remove();
          e.insert(i1, e1);
        }
    });
});
```